# Serverless ApiGatewayMethodOptions template error

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I'm trying to deploy AWS lambda using `sls deploy` command and got next error

```
Serverless Error ---------------------------------------

An error occurred while provisioning your stack: ApiGatewayMethodOptions - Template
error: API Gateway RestAPI nyq25wyiii doesn't exist.
```

Environment Information

```
   OS:                     linux
   Node Version:           4.2.6
   Serverless Version:     1.18.1
```

my `serverless.yml` looks like below

```
service: test_service

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: python3.6
  region: eu-west-1
  memorySize: 128

functions:
    test_function:
        handler: handler.handler
        events:
            - http:
                path: /
                method: any
                cors: true
```

Comment: Does it work if you restrict the method to `GET`?

Comment: @TrentBartlem no. same error